# AWS S3 how to allow acces only from specific domain?

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I would make the video available but only from my own domain. Do you think it is possible to set it up with AWS S3? Or anyway, this kind of intellectual property protection is not possible. If an asset is available on a website, people can download it anyway, right?!

If this is the case I should prevent the listing of the bucket and put salt in the name of the filename?

[image]

Comment: Please note that this type of security (using `aws:Referer`) is _very poor security_. It is easy to fake the `referer`, so it should _not_ be used for any data that you consider confidential. It is much better to implement security via Login authentication, and then only provide access to files via a [Amazon S3 pre-signed URL](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ShareObjectPreSignedURL.html), which is a time-limited URL that provides temporary access to a private object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need a custom policy for that.

```json
{
  "Version":"2021-11-13",
  "Id":"White list a specific http-referrer",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Sid":"Allow get requests originating from www.giuseppemandato.com",
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Principal":"*",
      "Action":"s3:GetObject",
      "Resource":"arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET_NAME/*",
      "Condition":{
        "StringLike":{"aws:Referer":["http://www.giuseppemandato.com/*","http://giuseppemandato.com/*"]}
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

---

You can flip it by stating `Effect: Deny` eventually, and ignore any req coming from the given domain.

---

- Also, check CORS configs here too https://www.eternalsoftsolutions.com/blog/how-to-restrict-s3-bucket-for-specific-domain-name/

Comment: eternal2020 is your bucket name?